# Найти кол-во строк в MySQL с определенным значением

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть таблица в MySQL:

```
id | name | sourse_id | 
1  | Alex | 1 
2  | John | 1
3  | Mike | 2
4  | Alex | 4
5  | Jane | 3
```

Логика проста - sourse_id - источник трафика. 
Как узнать, сколько человек пришло из источника 1, сколько из 2 и т.д.?
Думал сделать так

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
$sql  = 'SELECT sourse_id, name, id FROM users';
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result->execute();
$result = $result->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $res) {
  if ($res['sourse_id'] == 1) {
    $item['first_sourse']++;
  }
   if ($res['sourse_id'] == 2) {
    $item['second_sourse']++;
  }
  и т.д.
}
```

Но понимаю, что это не совсем правильно (не пишите про switch, тут просто показана логика). Вопрос следующий - как можно это оптимизировать?

Comment: `SELECT count(1) as src_count, sourse_id FROM users GROUP BY sourse_id ORDER BY sourse_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT source_id, COUNT(*) FROM users GROUP BY source_id
```